# how to configure Elastic Beanstalk to deploy code to an instance but not add it to the load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, daemon, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am moving a Rails app to AWS and am using EB. I need to run a daemon on a separate instance (I do not want this instance to be serving HTTP requests).

The daemon is part of app's codebase, and will communicate with the same RDS instance as the web server instances. I would like to know, if possible, how I can configure EB to deploy the rails app to an additional instance, but elide adding that instance to the load-balancer, and (re)start the daemon on that instance after a new revision is deployed.

I realize I could achieve the same result by managing this additional instance myself, outside of EB, but I have a feeling there's a better way. I have done some research myself, without finding what I'm after.

I could also just run the daemon on one of the web server instances, and live with the fact that it's also serving HTTP requests. Since this is acceptable for right now, that's what I'm doing today ... but I want a dedicated instance for that daemon, and it would be great if I didn't have to drop the convenience of EB deployments just for that.

This is the first time I've used Elastic Beanstalk; I have some experience with AWS. I hope my question makes sense. If it doesn't, an answer that points out why it doesn't make sense will be accepted.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI - I just released a gem that makes using eb much easier with rails https://github.com/alienfast/elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Elastic Beanstalk, this is typically achieved by using a **worker** tier environment within the same EB application (same code base, same `.eb*` files, just different environments.

Here's an example of a rails application that is deployed to one **web server**, and two specialized **workers**:

```
[yacin@mac my_rails_app (master)]$ eb list -v
Region: us-west-1
Application: my_rails_app
    Environments: 3
        email-workers-production : ['i-xxxxxxx']
        * web-servers-production : ['i-xxxxxx']
        job1-workers-production : ['i-xxxxxxx', 'i-xxxxxx']
```

The workers don't have a public HTTP interface and pull jobs from a queue shared with the front-end. 
The worker can be configured to have access the same database and with load balancing and autoscaling.

It's a very flexible and scalable approach, but will require some work to setup. Here's a couple of resources on the subject: [Amazon Worker Tier Video Tutorial](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1Y8QSQRL1KQZC/Elastic-Beanstalk-Video-Tutorial-Worker-Tier), [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html).

Comment: Hey, they added it! Good.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, though not straight forward, you could provide a `.config` file in `.ebextensions` to run your script files.

[This example of speeding up a deploy](http://horewi.cz/faster-rails-3-deployments-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk.html) shows running some scripts and moving data back and forth.  Better yet, the author describes the sequence and deployment process.

I'm just embarking on this type of container customization.  I have read of others dropping files in the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre` and `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post` directories, much of which can be derived by reading the post linked above.

Also note that you can include the `content` of a script in the yaml `.config` file such as this which I found yesterday:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
      cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT
      su -c "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pid-dir=$EB_CONFIG_APP_SUPPORT/pids restart" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, kross! It doesn't answer my question, though. The instance will still get added to the load balancer regardless of any custom scripts I add to the config; that is what I am (was) trying to prevent. I'm fairly confident now that this is not within the scope of EB and that managing the instance myself is The Way to do this.